# First sheaf cohomology of closed 1-forms on a homogeneous space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms, sheaf-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

Given a smooth quasi-projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$, is there a good way to compute the first sheaf cohomologiy $H^1(X,\Omega_{X,cl}^1)$ of closed 1-forms $\Omega_{X,cl}^1$?

What I'm mostly interested in is the case where $X = G/P$ is a homogeneous space of an algebraic group $G$, where $P$ is a closed subgroup. 
The case where $G$ is reductive and $P$ is a parabolic subgroup (so $X$ is projective) is my primary concern, but it'll be nice if a description for all algebraic groups can be found.

Motivation: $H^1(X,\Omega_{X,cl}^1)$ parametrizes all twisted sheaves of differential operators on $X$.

Some thoughts in the case where $G$ is reductive and $P = B$ is a Borel subgroup that may or may not help:

- We know $H^i(X,\Omega_X^1) = 0$ if $i \neq 1$ and is $\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{rank} G}$ if $i =1$. So the long exact sequence induced by $0 \to \Omega_{X,cl}^1 \to \Omega_X^1 \to \Omega_X^1/\Omega_{X,cl}^1 \to 0$ reduces to 
  $$0 \to H^0(X,\Omega_X^1/\Omega_{X,cl}^1) \to H^1(X,\Omega_{X,cl}^1) \to H^1(X,\Omega_X^1) \to H^1(X,\Omega_X^1/\Omega_{X,cl}^1) \to H^2(X,\Omega_{X,cl}^1) \to 0,$$
  but we need more knowledge of cohomologies of $\Omega_X^1/\Omega_{X,cl}^1$ to proceed.
- Homogeneous twisted sheaves of differential operators (htdo) are parametrized by $\mathfrak{b}/[\mathfrak{b},\mathfrak{b}]$ which has dimension $\mathrm{rank}G$. Therefore $H^1(X,\Omega_{X,cl}^1) \to H^1(X,\Omega_X^1)$ cannot be a proper injection.
- If we view $X$ as the variety of all Borel subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$, and let $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{B} \subset X \times \mathfrak g$ to be subbundles of $X \times \mathfrak g$ whose fibers at a point $x$ (which corresponds to a Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak b_x$) are $[\mathfrak{b}_x,\mathfrak{b}_x]$ and $\mathfrak b_x$, respectively, then we have an exact sequence of vector bundles $0 \to \mathcal B \to X \times \mathfrak g \to TX \to 0$ and the corresponding sequence $0 \to \mathfrak b^\circ \to \mathfrak g^\circ \to \mathcal T_X \to 0$ of sheaves; similarly if $\mathfrak n^\circ$ is the sheaf of $\mathcal N$ then 
  $$\Omega_X^1 \cong \mathfrak n^\circ = \big\{\sum_i h_i \otimes \xi_i \in \mathcal O_X \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathfrak  g = \mathfrak g^\circ \mid  \sum_i h_i(x) \otimes \xi_i \in [\mathfrak{b}_x,\mathfrak{b}_x] \big\}.$$
  Translating the pairing $\mathcal T_X \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \Omega_X^1 \to \mathcal O_X$ and the definition of exterior derivative on $\Omega_X^1$, one can write down a condition for a section $\sum_i h_i \otimes \xi_i \in \mathfrak n^\circ$ to be closed, namely that for any $\eta_1,\eta_2 \in \mathfrak g$ (viewed also as global vector fields on $X$), the function
  $$\sum_i \Big(  B(\xi_i,\eta_2) \eta_1(h_i) -  B(\xi_i,\eta_1) \eta_2(h_i) - B(\xi_i,[\eta_1,\eta_2]) h_i \Big) \in \mathcal O_X$$
  vanish, where $B(-,-)$ is the Killing form. But I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the long exact sequence in cohomology resulting from the short exact sequence of sheaves $0\to \Omega^1_{cl}\to \Omega^1\to \operatorname{Im}(\Omega^1\stackrel{d}{\to} \Omega^2)\to 0$ count as a good way?

Comment: @KReiser That's certainly the first tool that comes to mind, but it requires some knowledge of cohomologies of the sheaf of exact 2-forms

Comment: I apologize if it's not news to you, but it was not mentioned in your question, so I was unsure if you had considered it.

Comment: @KReiser No need to apologize! You reminded me that writing down some partial results might help understanding the question.